# django-s3direct multibytes uploading error

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-s3

When uploading the multibyte file such as (テスト.jpg) with [django-s3direct](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct)

This error comes in browser console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.includes is not a function (s3direct.js:51)
    at m.warn (s3direct.js:51:2581)
    at S.y.error (s3direct.js:44:28150)
```

If you don't use multibytes there is not error occurs.

Is there a any setting I should do for `S3` or `django-s3direct` ?

Comment: That looks like a JavaScript issue...

Comment: ah,You are right, thank you for adding the `javascript` tag

Comment: Also you probably might get a better/prompt response by filing an issue at the project's issue tracker, there really is nothing for us to work with unless we set up the infrastructure to attempt to reproduce the issue, as that is generally too much effort.  At the very least try to use the non-minified version of the JavaScript library `s3direct.js` to aid with debugging.